# Download resource image files using casperjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, casperjs, slimerjs

I read the documents and look like you need to have slimerjs http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html in order to get `responseData.body` from the `page.resource.received` event.

My use case is to download the images when the page is loaded so I don't do another round trip of: get the resource JSON, download and save any image file, reload the file to check for image dimension and if too small (icons) -> eliminate.

I am wondering if there is a better way to do this. I could in fact go do `evaluate` `img` selector but some websites use `background-url` css and that's tricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evaluate can be tricky, but here is a possible approach : (*PhantomJS Only*)

With  this example theres the possibility of

1. storing the `clipRects` of the images matching specific criteria for
   posterior `page.render()` of those elements into screen shot files.
2. storing the urls of the matching resources for posterior download
   requests
3. capturing the url inside 'src' attribute or the 'background-image' 
   css property, with an attempt of also obtaining the width & height for criteria *match-and-capture* purposes.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {console.log(msg);};
console.log('[#] I M A G E · N I N J A');
page.open('http://cartawifi.com', function(status) {
  var clipRectList = page.evaluate(function(pagex) {
    // .: Captured Images : In-Memory Reference Storage :.
    const IMAGES = {
        'src':{'indxs':[],'ref':[]},
        'background-image':{'indxs':[],'ref':[]},
        'selectors':[]
    }; 
    var clipRects = []; // maybe you want to take page screenshots of specific elements containing matching images
    var capturedImages = 0; var totalElements = 0;
    // .: Define Image Capture : Min/Max Width/Height :.
    const minWidth = 1; const minHeight = 1;
    const maxWidth = 9999;  const maxHeight = 9999;
    const regxp = new RegExp('url');
    $('*').each(function(index, el) { var ignore=false;
        // search for elements with 'background-image' css property
        if($(el).css('background-image')!=null!=null){
            var wu = $(this).css('width');
            var width = parseFloat(wu.replace('px',''));
            var hu = $(this).css('height');
            var height = parseFloat(wu.replace('px',''));
            var src = $(el).css('background-image');
            var group = "background-image"
            if(!src.match(regxp)){ignore=true;}else{
                //remove the keep the contents inside the 'url()' string'
                src = (($(el).css('background-image')).slice(4));
                src = src.substring(0, src.length - 1);
            }
        }
        // search for elements with 'src' html attribute
        else if($(el).attr('src')!=null){
            var width = $(this).get(0).naturalWidth; 
            var height = $(this).get(0).naturalHeight;
            var group = "src" 
            var src = $(el).attr('src');
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------
        if(width>=minWidth&&height>=minWidth&&
           width<=maxWidth&&height<=maxWidth&&
           !ignore){
                IMAGES[group].indxs.push(index); 
                IMAGES[group].ref.push(src); 
                IMAGES.selectors.push(this); 
                capturedImages++;
                console.log("  [captured] :",group,width,height,src);
                //:store clipRect for this element
                var clipR = $.extend({},$(el).offset(),{width: $(el).offsetWidth,height: $(el).offsetHeight});
                console.log("    (clipRect)",JSON.stringify(clipR));
                clipRects.push(clipR);
        }
        totalElements++;
    });
    // report information :
    console.log('[i] Total Elements Parsed : ',totalElements);
    console.log('[*] Total Images Captured : ',capturedImages);
    console.log('     >              [src] : ',IMAGES['src'].indxs.length);
    console.log('     > [background-image] : ',IMAGES['background-image'].indxs.length);
  });
  console.log('[!] TO-DO : STORE CAPTURED IMAGES AS FILES');
  phantom.exit();
});
```